# Need advice for Memory usage in perl

Tags: perl, memory-management

I am not new to perl , but I couldn't able to solve this usecase.

Here is my problem statement:

I am using Activestate perl 5.12 32-bit. I want to hold some 32 x 8MB array of double in Memory at a time. unfortunately, I am getting 'out of memory' error in this case. for example, the code below will lead to out of memory.

```
my $aref1 = [(.25) x (8*1024*1024)];
my $aref2 = [(.25) x (8*1024*1024)];
my $aref3 = [(.25) x (8*1024*1024)];
my $aref4 = [(.25) x (8*1024*1024)];
my $aref5 = [(.25) x (8*1024*1024)];
my $aref6 = [(.25) x (8*1024*1024)];
my $aref7 = [(.25) x (8*1024*1024)];
my $aref8 = [(.25) x (8*1024*1024)];
my $aref9 = [(.25) x (8*1024*1024)];
my $aref10 = [(.25) x (8*1024*1024)];
```

Is there any way to efficiently handle it?

**Note:** In any case, the access to the arrays is needed at any time of execution as fast as possible (since the user cannot wait soo long)

the options I have tried:

1. DBM::Deep - It takes more time
2. PDL - Gives 'out of memory' error for 32 x 8MB array of double

Awaiting your valuable suggestions!

Answer (score 11):

32 arrays * 8 Mi-doubles/array * 8 bytes/double = 2 GiB.

32-bit processes on Windows only have 2GiB of usable address space. Your raw data would take up all available address space, leaving nothing for the data structure's overhead, `perl`, your program and other variables. The only way it's going to fit in memory is if you switch to a 64-bit Perl. Otherwise, you will have to contend with a necessarily slower solution.

Comment: Yes. I could understand the problem now. So I am looking for any other intermediate solution (like [Inline::C](http://search.cpan.org/~sisyphus/Inline-0.51/C/C.pod), [Inline](http://search.cpan.org/~ingy/Inline-0.44/Inline.pod). Is it possible to store the data globally in Inline::C ?

Comment: No, the raw data takes more memory that you have. Switching language is not going to help. You need to switch to a 64-bit process or figure out a way of not having all the data in memory at once.

Answer (score 3):

This will create a perl value for each element, which will be quite heavy. You might want to look at something that stores the values as doubles, such as [Tie::CArray](https://metacpan.org/module/Tie%3a%3aCArray) or [Tie::Array::PackedC](https://metacpan.org/module/Tie%3a%3aArray%3a%3aPackedC).

Comment: Also, you might not want to create millions of temporary values in the process. Initializing in a loop might be much more feasible.

Answer (score 2):

Here is what I get on my Windows XP SP3 system using ActiveState Perl 5.14.2. Task manager was showing `Commit charge: 778M/3958M` when I ran the following script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use Devel::Size qw(total_size);

my $unit = 1024 * 1024;
my $topj = (8 * $unit) - 1;
my @data;

for my $i (0 .. 31) {
    print "$i: ";
    my @row;
    $#row = $topj;
    for my $j (0 .. $topj) {
        $row[$j] = 0.25;
    }
    push @data, \@row;
    printf "%.0f\n", total_size(\@data)/$unit;
}
```

Output:

```
C:\temp> yy
0: 224
1: 448
2: 672
3: 896
4: 1120
5: 1344
6: 1568
7: 1792
Out of memory!
8:
```

On the other hand, the following C program does better:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define ROWSIZE 8*1024*1024

int main(void) {
    int n = 1;
    while (calloc(ROWSIZE, sizeof(double))) {
        printf("%d: success!\n", n);
        n += 1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
1: success!
2: success!
3: success!
…
26: success!
27: success!
```

for the same 1.7GB footprint.

Comment: I am looking for any other intermediate solution (like [Inline::C](http://search.cpan.org/~sisyphus/Inline-0.51/C/C.pod), [Inline](http://search.cpan.org/~ingy/Inline-0.44/Inline.pod) ). Is it possible to store the data globally in Inline::C ?